# how can I display data in the desiered row of datagridview bounded with database

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am using datagridview as in pic

[image]

column named ID has combobox . and DGV bounded with database using Data Table .

working is as following :-

when I select value from combobox in row 1 , then it display data in corresponding rows(i.e row 1) .

Issue :-

When I select value from combobox in row 2 , it does not display data in row 2 ,but shows it data  in  row 1 (i.e replacing earlier data in row 1).

how I can display data in row 2 and similarly for all other rows keeping the data selected in previous rows safe .....

how combobox is getting filled  :-

```
   sqlCmd.Connection = con;
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT id FROM dgvdata";
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdap = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
        DataTable dtRecord = new DataTable();
        sqlDataAdap.Fill(dtRecord);
        comboBox1.DataSource = dtRecord;
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "id";
        con.Close();
```

how datagridview filled on selection on combobox :-

```
 con.Open();
        string sql = "select time,PARTY_NAME , DATE from dgvdata where id ='" + comboBox1.Text + "'";
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dataadapter.Fill(dt);
                   dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    con.close();
```

thanks in advance..

Comment: How is the combo box column added to the data grid view? You may have to show how you are creating the combo box column. I am guessing you are using the same data source for the combo boxes and the data grid view.

Comment: Just guessing… if ANY combo box selection is changed and following your code… would this change not simply “Replace” the current data grid views data table with the selected data? The last bit of code you showed is not “adding” to the current data grid view data table, but simply replaces it.

Comment: it might be . but that's all I have . .... thanks ..

Comment: Without more information, it sounds like you may need to make your own “Empty” data table. Set the `DataGridView.DataSource` to this empty table and “add” the rows to your new table. As you commented: _”but that's all I have”_ … and this is true, however… you can “make” what you need. Like an empty clone of the original data table.

Comment: so , How can i approach to this .....

Comment: Without knowing what you ultimately are trying to achieve, I am clueless as to the best approach. Can you explain what the goal is here? The way you are using the combo box “inside” the grid seems like an odd way to add items to the grid. Are you simply trying to get a unique group of records?  Without more info about what your requirements are, I feel speculation may be the best you can get.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140134/discussion-between-speedyraz-and-johng).